# Todo list in php

Tags: php

I'm building a simple todo list application in PHP.I am displaying the titles of all the todo list on one page via ajax using the following code

```
 $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT id, todo FROM todo");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{
$todo1 = $row["todo"];
$todofeed.='

<ul>
    <li>' . $todo1 . '</li>
</ul>   

';
  }
  print "$todofeed";
```

Now i want to create an interface in such a way that the user clicks on one todo list title and all items in that list are displayed via some jQuery effect...any way around this?? i jus need a direction...thanks :)

Comment: For every item you're creating a new `ul` list, I think you want to add a `li` element to one `ul` list instead.

Comment: Why a downvote? Isn't it a perfektly valid question? +1 to compensate from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch all the items of that todo list in a div with `display:none`.
Then , use Jquery .click to change its display attribute to visible.

```
<script>
$("#todolist_title").click(function() {
  $("#todolist_items").css('display' , 'visible');
});
</script>

<div id='todolist_title'>Title</div>
<br />
<div id='todolist_items' style='display:none'>
1.Item1<br />
2.Item2<br />
3.Item3<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice tutorial on how to create a todolist application with PHP and JQuery: [AJAX-ed Todo List With PHP, MySQL & jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/ajax-todo-list-jquery-php-mysql-css/)

Comment: i have seen that tutorial...it does not have the facility to create different todo lists its more of a single todo list...

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code on page where you want to populate todofeeds

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function todolist() {
$('#todolist').load("PHP Page Path Where you execute Query").slideDown();   
}
</script>

<div id="todolist" style="display:none"></div>
```

Please include Database connection on PHP page.